# bootstrap .list-group item stays active when leaving the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem where the mouse leaves the `.list-group` the last item to be 'hovered over' stays active but I need it to remove the `active` class.

Here is my function to add an `active` class on `mouseover`:

```
$('.list-group').on('mouseover','> a', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

That works fine but i need it to remove the `active` class on the last item to be hovered over when leaving the area.

Iv tried numerous amount of ways but cant seem to figure

Comment: Any special reason you aren't just using CSS for the hover effects? It's much more easier and reliable than using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these code :-

```
jQuery(".list-group").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
}, 
function () {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

It may help you.